# Como agrupar INPUTS no Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Eu queria que os campos de RG, Orgão Expedidor e UF juntos somassem o cumprimento do campo CPF Acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste seu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foi utilizado a `class` `row` do [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) e configurações das colunas `col-md-*` e `col-sm-*` para funcionar:

### Código exemplo:

<sup>**Visualmente na resposta não tem conferir, mas, em um região maior ele se adequa da maneira que espera.**</sup>

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row"> 
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">CPF</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="CPF">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">RG</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="RG">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Orgão Expedidor</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Orgão Expedidor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">UF</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="UF">
  </div>
</div>
```

Um exemplo no [***JsFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/mdtmot7r/)

<sub>***Observação:*** No [link da documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile) existe outros paramentos se for utilizar em celulares e dispositivos menores.</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Bootstrap 3: Criando Layouts e Grids](http://webdevacademy.com.br/tutoriais/ux/bootstrap-3-layouts-sistema-grids/)
- [Documentação Grid Boostrao](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
- [Documentação CSS Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: Eu gostaria que os 3 campos estivessem na mesma linha RG, Orgão Expedidor e UF

Comment: @ValterNegreiros [no exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/mdtmot7r/) não está como você quer?

Comment: Eu peguei o seu código e modifiquei, então eu tive o resultado esperado.

Comment: Em vez de 8-2-2, eu utilizei 4-4-4 e consegui colocar os 3 campos na mesma linha... MUITO OBRIGADO.

Answer (score 0):

No site oficial do Bootstrap existe um pequeno tutorial para isso:
"Controles de formulários individuais recebem automaticamente algum estilo global. Todos os elementos textuais , , e  com .form-control são ajustados para width: 100%; por padrão. Envolva labels e controles em .form-group para melhor espaçamento."

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Endereço de e-mail</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Senha</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Lembrando que essas classes só irão funcionar se estiver linkando ao css do Bootstrap**

Comment: Eu gostaria que os 3 campos estivessem na mesma linha RG, Orgão Expedidor e UF

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o seguinte: coloquei `<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4">`, nos 3 campos.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">RG</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="RG">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Orgão Expedidor</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Orgão Expedidor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">UF</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="UF">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Também está correto, colocando a númeração que você precisa. Eu coloquei como exemplo 8 2 2 (até a soma de 12 colunas), mas pode seguir qualquer GRID de sua preferencia. vlw